# about adding characters in all column names in R

Tags: r

I have a question. I imported a dataset from excel, but all column names are only numbers (e.g., 2,3,5,6,7) 
I just want to add "var" in front of number-only variables (e.g., var2, var3,var5...).
How can I do that?
I tried gsub, but failed.

Comment: Using `paste` `names(df1) <- paste0("var", names(df1))`

Answer (score 1):

What about only changing names for columns that don't contain letters

```
df <- tibble(
  `1` = rnorm(5), 
  `2` = rnorm(5), 
  x = rnorm(5), 
  y = rnorm(5)
)

names(df) <- ifelse(!grepl("[A-Za-z]", names(df)), paste0("var", names(df)), names(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var <- paste0("var", c(2,3,5))
names(df) <- var
```